# jquery validation popover position problem for select2 dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, validation, jquery-select2

I am displaying form validation error message in popover.it works proper for text element.but it's position is change for select2 element.it display popover error message in center of the field in text element but in select 2 element it display error message in left side corner how to display popover message in center for select2 error message

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  my_validate();
    $("#country_selF").select2();
})
var data_form = $( "#data_form" );
function my_validate(){
   data_form.validate( {
      rules: {
          country_name:{
                required:true
          },
          state_name :{
                required:true
               
          }
      },
      messages:{
          country_name:{
            required : "Select country name"
          },
          state_name:{
            required : 'Enter state name'
          }
      },
      errorClass: "my-error-class",
      showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
          $.each( this.successList , function(index, value) {
              $(value).popover('hide');
          }); 
          $.each( errorList , function(index, value) {
           
            var popoverDta = $(value.element).popover({
                  trigger   : 'manual',
                  placement : 'top',
                  content   : value.message,
                  template  : '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><div class="popover-content text-danger"><p></p></div></div></div>'
            });                      
            $(value.element).data('bs.popover').options.content = value.message;
                $(value.element).popover('show');
            });
      }        
  }); 
 }
 $(document).on('click',".save_btn",function(){
  if(data_form.valid() == true){
  }
  });
```

```css
form{
  margin:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- form start -->
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="data_form" id="data_form" action="http://172.16.20.9:1010/galaxy_vehicle_tracking/state_master.php" >
              <input type="hidden" name="fld_id" value="" id="fld_id">
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <!-- Country name -->
                  <label for="country_selF" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 control-label">Country Name</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <select  class="form-control custom_frm enb_dsb_fld"  placeholder="" name="country_name" value="" id="country_selF" style="width:100%;" ></select>
                  </div>
                  <!-- end of the Country Name --> 
                  <!-- state name -->       
                   <label for="state_name" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 control-label">State Name</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control enb_dsb_fld mv_next" id="state_name"  name="state_name" required="required">
                  </div>         
                  <!-- end of the state name -->
                </div><!-- end of the form group -->               
              <!-- /.box-body -->
              <div class="box-footer" style="text-align: right;" id="btn_box">
                <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: right;" id="btn_box">             
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save_btn btn-sm" id="save_btn">Save</button>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.box-footer -->
            </form>
```

Comment: Why I am getting negative votes on it?what is wrong in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing this with css. Please review my css code **Carefully**,

Let me know further clarification

Hope it will help you. :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  my_validate();
  $("#country_selF").select2();
})
var data_form = $( "#data_form" );
function my_validate(){
 data_form.validate( {
    rules: {
        country_name:{
              required:true
        },
        state_name :{
              required:true
             
        }
    },
    messages:{
        country_name:{
          required : "Select country name"
        },
        state_name:{
          required : 'Enter state name'
        }
    },
    errorClass: "my-error-class",
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        $.each( this.successList , function(index, value) {
            $(value).popover('hide');
        }); 
        $.each( errorList , function(index, value) {
         
          var popoverDta = $(value.element).popover({
                trigger   : 'manual',
                placement : 'top',
                content   : value.message,
                template  : '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><div class="popover-content text-danger"><p></p></div></div></div>'
          });                      
          $(value.element).data('bs.popover').options.content = value.message;
              $(value.element).popover('show');
          });
    }        
}); 
}
$(document).on('click',".save_btn",function(){
if(data_form.valid() == true){
}
});
```

```css
form{
  margin:50px;
}
.popover.top>.arrow{
  left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
.popover.top{
  left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.1/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- form start -->
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="data_form" id="data_form" action="http://172.16.20.9:1010/galaxy_vehicle_tracking/state_master.php" >
              <input type="hidden" name="fld_id" value="" id="fld_id">
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <!-- Country name -->
                  <label for="country_selF" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 control-label">Country Name</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <select  class="form-control custom_frm enb_dsb_fld"  placeholder="" name="country_name" value="" id="country_selF" style="width:100%;" ></select>
                  </div>
                  <!-- end of the Country Name --> 
                  <!-- state name -->       
                   <label for="state_name" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 control-label">State Name</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control enb_dsb_fld mv_next" id="state_name"  name="state_name" required="required">
                  </div>         
                  <!-- end of the state name -->
                </div><!-- end of the form group -->               
              <!-- /.box-body -->
              <div class="box-footer" style="text-align: right;" id="btn_box">
                <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align: right;" id="btn_box">             
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save_btn btn-sm" id="save_btn">Save</button>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.box-footer -->
            </form>
```